# jQuery Sortable sorts only the handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, handle

I want to drag some divs, but only on the y-axis. By using draggable its possible, but it have to be sorted between the other divs when dropped. So i chose sortable.
I have to use a handle-div, but its not working. Alle the examples on google and here are working, except mine.

Do you have any hints for me?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rQ8wu/

The JS-Part is the problem:

```
$('.block').sortable({
    handle: '.handle',
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

**What he is doing**: Moving the handle only.

**What he should do**: Move the whole div (class "block").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the wrong div. You need to call `sortable` on the div that contains the `.block` divs.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rVDu2/

Comment: Thanks. Without the handle its working on this div - that's why I was confused.